# Firebase notification setSound() not working with React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification

i'm trying to create a channel to receive notification with sound, i'm sending the notificatiton from the **Firebase Cloud Messaging** and i setted the Sound to Actived. I do have a file inside **android/app/src/main/res/raw named alert.mp3** and i've tried to use **.setSound('alert.mp3')**. Here's my current code:

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications
        .Android.Channel('tarotPt', 'Tarot Pt', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
        .setSound('alert')
        .enableLights(true)
        .enableVibration(true);

    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days struggling with this, i found out that my code was working fine, the problem was on my Emulator. I was using the Android Studio Emulator, when i use a real device, it work fine.